How to fix error: API key not found. Check that <meta-data android:name.....> is in AndroidManifest.xml

I'm new to react native/expo SDK 51 and trying to create a build for android atm
I see there are other questions similar to this which add the key to AndroidManifest.xml file but that file gets wiped out with
npx expo prebuild --clean

after making changes, the expo docs say to add the key to app.config like so
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "package": "com.anonymous.maps1"
    },

but it doesn't transfer to androidmanifest.xml after running with
npx expo run:android

the error above shows in the app, the app is using react-native-maps
